# POST Basic Authentication Api HttpEndpoint Wso2 EI

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, rest, wso2-esb

How can I use httpEndpoint wso2 ei to post api to get token?
Below is code to call api but it has 405 error. I make sure the api has POST method.
What does it wrong?

```
<api context="/default" name="PostToken" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <root xmlns="">
                                <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
                                <client_id>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</client_id>
                                <client_secret>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</client_secret>
                            </root>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <call>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="https://example.com/token">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </call>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: You have exposed the resource with the POST method. Are you calling the above API with HTTP POST? How does the client is calling the above API?

Comment: Thanks for your question! Thanks for it, I realized and fixed the error